# What is installed with the `mail-server` metapackage installed from `tasksel`?

Tags: mail-server, tasksel

I'm in the need of installing the `mail-server` metapackage on my Ubuntu Server 15.10 machine.

I have installed the `mail-server` metapackage with the `sudo tasksel` command; but I'm not sure what to do next.

As [a Google search shows](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=ubuntu%20%2B%20mail%20server%20%2B%20tasksel), we have the official guide/intro [from ubuntu.com here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MailServer); this shows us:

1. Mail Transfer Agent to `send and receive` emails
2. Mail filtering to `filter` emails
3. Mail Delivery Agent for `IMAP/POP3 protocols` support
4. Webmail for `web-interface-based email` checking
5. Mailing lists for `mailing lists` with email group

My question is which of the above 5 modules does the `mail-server` metapackage of `tasksel` install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the full list of packages installed by `sudo tasksel mail-server` on Ubuntu 15.10 *Desktop* (I suppose the list may vary across releases):

```
% tasksel --task-packages mail-server | sort
bsd-mailx
dovecot-core
dovecot-imapd
dovecot-pop3d
libassuan0
libexttextcat-2.0-0
libexttextcat-data
libgpgme11
liblockfile1
liblockfile-bin
libpython2.7-minimal
libpython2.7-stdlib
libpython-stdlib
libtokyocabinet9
libwrap0
lockfile-progs
mutt
ntpdate
postfix
procmail
python
python2.7
python2.7-minimal
python-minimal
ssl-cert
tcpd
```

On Ubuntu 15.10 *Server* the following packages are missing from the above list:

```
libexttextcat-2.0-0
libexttextcat-data
liblockfile1
liblockfile-bin
lockfile-progs
ntpdate
```

So:

1. `postfix`
2. None of those. You'll have to pick an option and install additional packages.
3. `dovecot`
4. None of those. You'll have to pick an option and install additional packages.
5. None of those. You'll have to pick an option and install additional packages.

Comment: Excellent & fast answer. I learned a lot. Thank you!

Comment: @NamGVU Glad that it helped :)

Comment: @NamGVU This is on Ubuntu 15.10 *Desktop* though, you may want to double-check that the list corresponds in Ubuntu 15.10 *Server*.

Comment: Sure I will; guess it is the same.

Comment: I have checked on Ubuntu Server and here are the ones in your list that not found 
`libexttextcat-2.0-0
libexttextcat-data
liblockfile1
liblockfile-bin
lockfile-progs
ntpdate`